# Unresolved reference to X module with Flask app in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

```
flask 
   utils
     __init__.py
     database.py
     redis.py
     config.py
   app.py
   requirements.txt
   ...
```

I'm having issues with PyCharm stating "Unresolved reference to utils" with the above project structure.

I have `from utils import config` in app.py and PyCharm is happy. No warning.

But in utils/database.py I have `from utils import config` and it is underlined in red and I get the warning `Unresolved reference to utils`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i believe this has to do with how pycharm is resolving your modules and packages inside your project, and how you are attempting to import your package.
While the code should run no problem, python is a bit smarter than pycharm in figuring out what is where, you are passing an incomplete absolute reference to your package.

either should work, but depends more on how you want to run your program - i.e whether you are packaging it, running from cli, from repl, etc.

absolute import - `from flask.utils import config`
relative import - `from . import config`

this is some good read on imports: https://realpython.com/python-import/

Answer (score 0):

Try marking directory "flask" as Sources Root (right-click on directory -> **Mark Directory as** -> **Sources Root**).

Docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html#mark-dir-project-view